# wordpress custom rewrite rule to external non-wordpress php page

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Hello Everyone and thank you for your help!

I have an external (outside wordpress in root directory) php file that I would like to use the custom_rewrite_rule function to make the url pretty as well as pass on information for variables that will look up an API record from that URL. You might ask why I haven't done it the regular way and made it a page template inside wordpress, and that is because I am using a custom JQuery slideshow that seems to have trouble running inside a wordpress environment.

So what I have in my child themes functions.php is:

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
add_rewrite_rule('^yacht-details/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','yacht-details.php?info=$matches[1]&boatid=$matches[2]','top');}


add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

and in the php file am using the standard $_GET to acquire the information.

```
$info = $_GET["info"];
$boatid = $_GET["boatid"];
```

My actual problem is what I am actually getting is literally $matches[1] and $matches[2] instead of the variables.

What am I doing wrong? Does this need to be done with .htaccess instead of functions.php? The problem I run in to going that route is wordpress does not seem to like more than one subfolder.

Thank you again.

Comment: Do not forget to flush and regenerate the rewrite rules database after modifying rules. From WordPress Administration Screens, Select Settings -> Permalinks and click Save Changes without any changes.

Comment: i tried that wp78de, hasn't made a difference :(